# Merge multiple different array values of same length with a delimiter in a final single array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 3 different array with same length

```
var title = ['title 1','title 2','title 3'];    
var description = ['description 1','description 2','description 3'];    
var link = ['link 1','link 2','link 3'];
```

How can I merge all array values in to a single array with a pipe - `|` -  delimiter?

Result:

```
final_arr = [
  'title 1|description 1|link 1',
  'title 2|description 2|link 2',
  'title 3|description 3|link '
]
```

Comment: Anything you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
title.map((x,i) => `${x}|${description[i]}|${link[i]}`);
```

we use here standard js 'tools' with good documentation: [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and fact that each array has same number of elements

```js
var title = ['title 1','title 2','title 3'];

var description = ['description 1','description 2','description 3'];

var link = ['link 1','link 2','link 3'];

var r = title.map((x,i) => `${x}|${description[i]}|${link[i]}`);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a class assignment... :)

```
 var A=[];

 for(var i=0; i<title.length; i++){

 A.push(title[i]+'|'+description[i]+'|'+link[i]);

 }
```

That's a nice basic solution your teacher can't refuse!

Answer (score 0):

Do with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) .Based on index Match

```js
var title = ['title 1','title 2','title 3'];
var description = ['description 1','description 2','description 3'];
var link = ['link 1','link 2','link 3'];

var res= title.map((a,b)=> a+'|'+description[b]+'|'+link[b]);
console.log(res)
```

OR `Array#ForEach`

```js
var title = ['title 1','title 2','title 3'];
var description = ['description 1','description 2','description 3'];
var link = ['link 1','link 2','link 3'];

var res =[];
title.forEach((a,b)=> res.push(a+'|'+description[b]+'|'+link[b]));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the arrays.

```js
const
    title = ['title 1', 'title 2', 'title 3'],
    description = ['description 1', 'description 2', 'description 3'],
    link = ['link 1', 'link 2', 'link 3'],
    result = [title, description, link].reduce((a, b) => a.map((v, i) => v + '|' + b[i]));
     

console.log(result);
```